# How to fetch single repository from octokit gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, octokit

I am beginner to ruby
I am try to fetch data from "octokit gem"
i need information of single repository using it's id,

i try a simple code of it but it list out my all repository

```
require 'octokit'


=> true
2.2.4 :003 > user = Octokit.user 'parth1634'
 => {:login=>"parth1634", :id=>8487101, :avatar_url=>"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/8487101?v=3", :gravatar_id=>"", :url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634", :html_url=>"https://github.com/parth1634", :followers_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/followers", :following_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/following{/other_user}", :gists_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/gists{/gist_id}", :starred_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/starred{/owner}{/repo}", :subscriptions_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/subscriptions", :organizations_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/orgs", :repos_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/repos", :events_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/events{/privacy}", :received_events_url=>"https://api.github.com/users/parth1634/received_events", :type=>"User", :site_admin=>false, :name=>"Parth Patel", :company=>"BoTree Technologies.Pvt.Ltd", :blog=>"https://parthpatelsblog.wordpress.com/", :location=>"Visnagar, Gujarat.", :email=>"parth1634@gmail.com", :hireable=>nil, :bio=>nil, :public_repos=>10, :public_gists=>1, :followers=>3, :following=>6, :created_at=>2014-08-19 05:23:02 UTC, :updated_at=>2016-03-02 04:22:46 UTC}
2.2.4 :004 > repos = user.rels[:repos].get.data
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your current code returns data for 11 repos that you have. If you only want to return the data for the one data that you specify the :id for, do it like this:

```
repos = user.rels[:repos].get.data.select {|r| r[:id] == 35797521 }
```

Replace with the actual id that you're looking for!